# Rotation of plane curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, plane-geometry, plane-curves

Given the curve $y^2 = x^3 - 10x + 10$, which looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to prove whether or not there exists an equation of an algebraic curve such that its graph would correspond to a rotation of the above given curve, e.g., the rotation about the origin (please forgive my Paint skills):

[image]

Mostly, I'm looking for a way to only simply study whether there is any way to make sense of the above question, so as to see whether there exists an equation which corresponds to the rotated curve. Is there any specific concepts I could begin studying to approach the question? Thank you!

Comment: every rotation is the application of a linear transformation, so ... I certainly hope so?

Comment: @DanUznanski this is also what I thought, but isn't this not so obvious the moment one asks whether there exists an algebraic representation of this rotation? e.g., we know that y = 2x can be taken to be a representation of a rotation of y = x, but it seems to me way less obvious for something like the above mentioned curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the $2D$ curve's equation be $g(x,y) = 0$. **Note that rotation about the origin in $2D$ is the same as rotation about the $z$-axis in $3D$.**

**Rotation about $z$-axis**: Let $R_{z,\theta}$ denote the rotation matrix for a rotation of angle $\theta$ about the z-axis and let $(x',y',z')^T := R_{z,\theta} (x_0,y_0, 0)^T$.

$ \begin{align*}
R_{z,\theta} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & - \sin \theta & 0  \\
\sin \theta &  \cos \theta  & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} &\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x' &= (\cos \theta) x_0 - (\sin \theta) y_0 \\
y' &= (\sin \theta) x_0 + (\cos \theta) y_0  \\
z' &= 0
\end{cases} \\ &\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x_0 &= (\cos \theta) x' + (\sin \theta) y' \\
y_0 &= - (\sin \theta) x' + (\cos \theta) y'  \\
0 &= z'
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$

So on rotating the curve $g(x,y) = 0$ around the $z$-axis by angle $\theta$, the equation of the curve we get is:
$$g((\cos \theta) x' + (\sin \theta) y', - (\sin \theta) x' + (\cos \theta) y') = 0$$
We can't eliminate $\theta$ from this equation to get a single equation for the curve formed by rotating $g(x,y) = 0$ by $2\pi$ in this case.

Comment: The OP is asking for a rotation about the origin in 2D.

Comment: My bad I'll edit my answer.

Comment: hm, in this case the sought-after result would be obtained by a combination of x-axis and y-axis rotations?

Comment: ah sorry did not realize you were working on it, will reread

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Which bit doesn't make sense?

Comment: selected as the best answer, but it would make sense to remove the bits on x-axis and y-axis rotation!

Comment: I've removed those bits.

Comment: @Kaind quick question here: the extended answer was helpful for helping me figure out how to solve the problem, I'm just wondering about a particular detail of notation: $(x',y',z') := R_{z,\theta} (x_0,y_0, 0)^T$ how come there's a transposition here? Isn't the system of equations of first inference, $x' = ...$, $y' = ...$, $z' =  ...$ without a transposition?

Comment: That's just matrix multiplication. The rotation matrix is a $3 \times 3$ vector. Hence you can only post multiply a $3 \times 1 $ vector. $[x_0 y_0 0]$ is a $1 \times 3$ matrix. And so technically it should be $(x',y',z')^T = R (x_0, y_0 , 0)^T$.

Comment: right! thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate your curve cut out by $f(x,y)$ by an angle $\theta$ around the origin, then you want to make a linear change of coordinates by letting $x_{old}=x_{new}\cos(-t)-y_{new}\sin(-t)$ and $y_{old}=x_{new}\sin(-t)+y_{new}\cos(-t)$. It's immediately apparent that the curve you get is also algebraic, with equation $f(x_{new}\cos(-t)-y_{new}\sin(-t),x_{new}\sin(-t)+y_{new}\cos(-t))$.

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @Kaind when I wrote my answer, I still saw your post discussing 3D surfaces. I don't understand why you've kept that discussion in there - that's not what the question's about.

Comment: this answer was just as good as the other one!